# Is mac address based security for single user Web Application a good idea?

Tags: networking, security, web

I made my first web application dedicated to a single user.

Being a system administrator it would be simpler for me to lockdown security on the operating system side rather than on the session side.

I thought of a simple solution: allowing port 80 only to his mac address.

Is this a good idea?

Which flaws should I care about?

Comment: MAC address can be spoofed though. Can you not just set a username / password on the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought of a simple solution: allowing port 80 only to his mac address.

"Simple" how? In the OSI model...

- [MAC addresses are a part of layer 2.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control)
- [TCP port numbers are layer 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_4_protocols_.28Transport_Layer.29), sitting on top of [IP at layer 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_3_protocols_.28Network_Layer.29).
- [HTTP is layer 7.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_%28OSI_model%29#Layer_7_protocols_.28Application_Layer.29)

By the time you are dealing with TCP port numbers, you are no longer dealing with hardware addresses. Hence, mixing the two, even if the software allows it in the first place, is seriously ill-advised. And as was pointed out in [a comment to this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/557483/is-mac-address-based-security-for-single-user-web-application-a-good-idea#comment645791_557513) by [Chris McKeown](https://serverfault.com/users/115117/chris-mckeown), unless the two hosts are on the same network segment, *it is highly likely that any MAC address you will see is that of the closest router* anyway and not the end-user's machine at all.

Also, remember that MAC addresses are easily changed even if you are willing to accept the constraint of the two machines having to be on the same network segment. If the end user for some reason gets a different network card, it will almost certainly have a different MAC address. Many NICs today have software-definable MAC addresses. Plus of course, suppose someone else uses the user's PC; should they gain unfettered access to the application? Even if this is basically a hobby endaevor, I would hope not.

In the end, I strongly agree with [kafka's comment to the question](https://serverfault.com/questions/557483/is-mac-address-based-security-for-single-user-web-application-a-good-idea#comment645751_557483): why not **just use username/password authentication**?

If you don't want to deal with doing authentication yourself in the code and especially if you don't need to separate access based on credentials (though that is still very much a possibility), just offload the authentication work to the web server through for example [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: Indeed. Depending on the network topology, the source MAC address that the server sees will probably be that of the local router anyway.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown Good point in mentioning that; I'm going to steal it and edit that into the answer...

Comment: Agreed!

I'll do it using php.

Also thanks for pointing out .htaccess!

Answer (score 0):

It's very bad idea. Mac address can be easily changed. Moreover, network filtering it's only tiny part of secure systems. It's main purpose is to restrict communication to valid traffic (prevent receive crafted packets, traffic from/to some networks, etc.)

You should provide security on all system/app stack levels.